# How to make this icon hover effect?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

Can you somebody tell me how can I create hover effect of background and icon? Because all icons have same class name.

This is a code of facebook

```
<div class="vc_icon_element vc_icon_element-outer vc_icon_element-align-center vc_icon_element-have-style">
    <div class="vc_icon_element-inner vc_icon_element-color-custom vc_icon_element-have-style-inner vc_icon_element-size-xl vc_icon_element-style-rounded vc_icon_element-background vc_icon_element-background-color-white">
        <span class="vc_icon_element-icon typcn typcn-social-facebook" style="color:#000000 !important"></span><a class="vc_icon_element-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/" title="" target=" _blank"></a></div>
</div>
```

This is a code of twitter

```
<div class="vc_icon_element vc_icon_element-outer vc_icon_element-align-center vc_icon_element-have-style">
<div class="vc_icon_element-inner vc_icon_element-color-custom vc_icon_element-have-style-inner vc_icon_element-size-xl vc_icon_element-style-rounded vc_icon_element-background vc_icon_element-background-color-white">
    <span class="vc_icon_element-icon typcn typcn-social-twitter" style="color:#000000 !important"></span><a class="vc_icon_element-link" href="https://twitter.com/" title="" target=" _blank"></a></div>
```

Comment: Probably a sprite is used moving the background position on hover.

Comment: Please add some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe target that  `.vc_icon_element` and add something like this:

```
.vc_icon_element:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

or to target that span

```
.vc_icon_element:hover span {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Now it works for background, but need make hover for icon too, can you help me?

Comment: You can target the vc_icon_element-icon also, so when your .vc_icon_element is hovered, you could just add vc_icon_element-icon onto the end. For example:

.vc_icon_element:hover .vc_icon_element-icon {
     color: blue;
}

Comment: So if the element of the background is: .facebook-ikona and element of the icon is .typcn-social-facebook how will look the structure? Im little confused.

Comment: in that scenario it would be .facebook-ikona .vc_icon_element-background:hover .typcn-social-facebook { color: blue; }

Comment: Try that again, I edited the code slightly based on what your background worked on